# Numpy skip all values by one and create an array from this

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a kinda ugly snippet of code that takes an array `a`, skips the i-th element `np.hstack([a[:i], a[i+1:])` of this array, and appends it to the result array. I wonder whether there is any fancy way (without manual for-loops) to do the following:

```
[a, b, c] -> [[b, c], [a, c], [a, b]]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you might be looking for the itertools combinations method.

Comment: What is the len of the array. How do you want it to be grouped. How many groups or arrays.

Comment: Can you actually show the array you are working with, as well as an expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with `masking` -

```
def skip_one(a):
    n = len(a)
    return np.repeat(a[None],n,axis=0)[~np.eye(n,dtype=bool)].reshape(n,-1)
```

**Alternative #1 :**

Save on memory with the replication, use `np.broadcast_to(a,(n,n))` to replace `np.repeat(a[None],n,axis=0)`.

**Alternative #2 :**

Replace last step with `np.tile` based code to bring in more *compact-ness* -

```
np.tile(a,(n,1))[~np.eye(n,dtype=bool)].reshape(n,-1)
```

**Alternative #3 :**

Use a custom made mask. Hence, replace the second step with -

```
np.broadcast_to(a,(n,n))[np.not_equal.outer(*[range(n)]*2)].reshape(n,-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [22]: a
Out[22]: array([4, 7, 3, 8])

In [23]: skip_one(a)
Out[23]: 
array([[7, 3, 8],
       [4, 3, 8],
       [4, 7, 8],
       [4, 7, 3]])
```

Comment: thanks, neat idea, but shouldn't the parameters of last `reshape` be in the tuple?

Comment: checked the ndarray.reshape docs, it allows to inline shape parameters

Comment: one more question, is `not_equal` more effective than using python `!=` operator? I guess that `not_equal` exploits the knowledge of fixed array type making it faster, in comparison with searching for the implementation of `__ne__`

Comment: @andrhua Here that one has a method `outer`, which we need. So. it makes sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what (I presume) you did in a list comprehension:

```
[np.hstack((data[:i],data[i+1:])) for i in range(len(data))]
```